# generate data from formatted string

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, string-formatting

I have this code to Format an string

```
string s = "the first number is: {0} and the last is: {1} ";
int first = 2, last = 5;
string f = String.Format(s, first, last);
```

I want to extract `first` and `last` from final formatted string(`f`).It means I want to de-format the `f` to extract `first` and `last`(I have the format base(`s`)).

there is a way that is this:

- extract them using `string.Split()`(hard and bad way)

but I think there is a simple solution in .Net but I don't know what is this.

can anybody tell me what is the simple way?

Comment: In the future, it would be better if you edited your old question, instead of deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: Also, why are you even trying to do this? There's probably a better solution.

Comment: @svick: It got -3 votes because I didn't tell my question correct. and if I did that It got more that -3 votes and I couldn't get my answer :(

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked you why are you trying to do this. If you explained that, maybe someone can provide you with a better solution that parsing the string.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: the thing is that if you *know* that you will need `first` and `last` just hold them somewhere and pas that values, and not reparse the string previously composed by them... the easiest solution in *this* case if use of `Split(new char[]{':',' '})` on the string and pick ever 6th element (`first` and `second`).

Comment: @Tigran: I think there is a **better** way than using `Split()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not using some regex here ?

```
string s = "the first number is: {0} and the last is: {1} ";
int first = 2, last = 5;
string f = String.Format(s, first, last);

string pattern = @"the first number is: ([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) and the last is: ([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) ";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = regex.Match(f);
if (match.Success)
{
    string firstMatch = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string secondMatch = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

You can obviously make it more robust with proper error checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to achieve it in a more dynamic fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
        string s = "the first number is: {0} and the last is: {1} ";
        int first = 2, last = 5;
        string f = String.Format(s, first, last);
        Regex rex = new Regex(".*the first number is: (?<first>[0-9]) and the last is: (?<second>[0-9]).*");
        var match = rex.Match(f);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["first"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["second"].ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Either I'm not interpreting you correctly or vice-versa...  What I've done is give you a way of retrieving named groups from a regex by name. That's what the angle brackets are for, in the regex pattern. That way you avoid using int indexers. I'm not sure what you meant in your reply... Anyway, I see you have a solution, so no matter.